# Trying to display information from a database table into a list box

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, database, visual-studio

I'm currently attempting to create an asp.net web application in c# using Visual Studio and could use some help.

One of my web pages is a registration page, you select a radio button (parent or child) and proceed to fill out the form. I have it working so that depending on which radio button you selected, the information is stored in either the parent or the children tables within my database.

The issue i'm having is that the next step requires me to display the children's details (name, username & DOB). I was hoping to display the data in a table but have had no luck with the examples i've tried to follow and other things I have tried myself. My next idea was to use a list box, and using the commented out section shown in my code, I managed to display to children in the table, but all on one line.

As my code is shown right now, an error is appearing under the 'Add' in 'ListBox1.Items.Add(reader...'. It says No overload for method 'Add' takes 3 arguments. I have tried various fixes that I found here and elsewhere on the net, but nothing worked.

Would anyone be able to advise me how to get the values to appear correctly (1 child per line) or even how to correctly use a table to display the children?

Thanks in advance!

[image: Error regarding SqlDataAdapter]

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Collections;


namespace Coursework
{
public partial class View_remove_children : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection connect = new SqlConnection("Data Source=THEBEAST;Initial Catalog=newregDB;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False");

        connect.Open();

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT [firstname], [dob], [ChildID] FROM [children]");
        cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
        cmd.Connection = connect;

        //string temp = "";

        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            {
                //temp += reader["firstname"].ToString();
                //temp += reader["dob"].ToString();
                //temp += reader["gender"].ToString();
                //temp += "<br/>";
                ListBox1.Items.Add(reader["firstname"], reader["dob"], reader["ChildID"]);

            }

            connect.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: You should consider wrapping your `SqlConnection` in a `using` block. Currently, `Close()` might not be called if an exception is thrown.

Comment: please learn proper syntax when coding you do not need double `{` insdie of this  `while (reader.Read()){` also understand what happens in Page_Load as well as PostBacks or `!IsPostBack` also use the .ToString() when working with reader objects another suggestion is to use the debugger.. can you see in the debugger if the items are being added..? I would suggest using a DataGrid to inside of a webpage to display the results returned from the query as well.. lots of awesome working examples on how to do this on the web..

Comment: also if the Select statement since the column names are not reserved words there is no need to wrap the column names around a `[ ]`

Comment: I forgot to mention that I am extremely new to c# & asp.net so a lot of that information does not mean a lot to me. Are you basically saying that this whole block of code should not even be inside the page load? My understanding was that anything within page load would be executed as the page is loaded. I want the children entries from my database table to be visible as this page loads so thought it made sense? I also added the .ToString() after each entry (firstname, dob & childID) but I still got the overload for 3 arguments error.

Comment: @ACostea we understand that you maybe new to .net and C# however you are not new to using the internet so keep in mind that there are tons of free tutorials online in regards to learning `C# Basics`

Comment: And I have been getting by purely on said free tutorials, I understand that my syntax wasn't perfect in that example but the reason I came here is that none of the material I could find online related to the issue i'm having..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you need table view you better use GridView for that, drag and drop GridView control to your designer view and do as below

```
using(SqlConnection connect = new SqlConnection("Data Source=THEBEAST;Initial Catalog=newregDB;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False"))
using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT [firstname], [dob], [ChildID] FROM [children]", connect))
{
    connect.Open();
    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    sda.Fill(dt);
    GridView1.DataSource = dt; //give your gridview name here
    GridView1.DataBind();//give your gridview name here
}
```

try few tutorials about gridview grouping, edit, insert etc.. then you can decide yourself is this suitable for your requirements or not.

[Implement GridView Grouping: Group similar GridView Rows in ASP.Net](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Implement-GridView-Grouping-Group-similar-GridView-Rows-in-ASPNet.aspx)

[Simple Insert Select Edit Update and Delete in ASP.Net GridView control](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Simple-Insert-Select-Edit-Update-and-Delete-in-ASPNet-GridView-control.aspx)

Comment: you could refactor that down to use less code as well for example 
`new SqlDataAdapter(cmd).Fill(dt);` but you would have to wrap the cmd around a `using(){ }` to take advantage of this I would post an example but what you have should do the trick. Personally I would use 2 using statements one outer for the constring and the other for the command

Comment: Thank you for the example, before I attempt to implement this, one thing I should add. Eventually, I need to be able to view the children based on their age groups (6-10, 11-13, 14-16) and even remove a child. Does a grid view give me that kind of flexibility? Thanks again.

Comment: you need to setup filtering or alter your query so that you can pass in parameters in the Select statement

Comment: So I am going to use GridView after looking at the tutorials you posted, it seems like it will do what I need. After using the code you provided, i'm now getting an error at SqlDataAdapter, it is saying 'The type or namespace name 'SqlDataAdapter' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Data'. It was working earlier, is there a reason why it is not now? Thanks! EDIT - I am using System.Data.SqlClient and System.Data on this page also.

Comment: @ACostea there was a spelling mistake, check you have `SqlDataAdapter ` in both places

Comment: I thought that, as I have had similar issues but I re-typed it all just to make sure and I still have the error. I have uploaded an image on my original post to show.

Comment: just use the `SqlDataAdapter ` or you need to use `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter`

Comment: Ok thanks, I have it working. Just have to play around with attempting to filter, delete etc now! Thank you for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

I would store the connection string in a .Config file then I would do the following and place this code inside of a static method for example

```
public static DataTable SelectData()
{
    var ConnString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["YourConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    SqlDataAdapter sda;
    DataTable dt;
    using (SqlConnection connStr = new SqlConnection(ConnString))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT firstname, dob, ChildID FROM children", connStr))
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            dt = new DataTable();
            new SqlDataAdapter(cmd).Fill(dt);
        }
    }
    return dt;
}
```